# Uable to send POST data to JSON file via JQuery/AJAX, Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I am learning to process JQuery/Ajax from this video on **YouTube**, [click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5nL7X1UMWsc&t=94s)..

I'm not having any problem in receiving data from **order.json** file but when I am trying to **POST** data. I am always getting **Error**.

The **code structure** with **screenshot** and **code** is below, please help me.

**Project folder screenshot:**

[image]

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<h1>Jquery  Ajax Tutorial</h1>

<h3>Coffie Orders</h3>

<ul id="orders"></ul>

<h4>Add a Coffie Order</h4>
<p>  Name: <input type="text" id="name"> </p>
<p>  Drink: &nbsp;<input type="text" id="drink"> </p>
<button id="add-order">Add!</button>
```

**JQuery/Ajax code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var $orders = $('#orders');

  var $name = $('#name');
  var $drink = $('#drink');

  function addOrder(order){
    $orders.append('<li>Name: '+ order.name +', Drink: '+ order.drink +'</li>');
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/api/orders.json',
    success: function (orders) {
      $.each(orders, function(i, orders) {
        addOrder(orders);
      });
    },
    error: function(){
      alert('Error Loading Page');
    }
  });

  $('#add-order').click(function(){
    var order = {
      name: $name.val(),
      drink: $drink.val(),
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/api/orders.json',
      data: order,
      success: function(newOrder) {
        addOrder(newOrder);
      },
      error: function(){
        alert('Error Adding Orders');
      }
    });
  });

});
```

**JSON: order.json**

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "James",
    "drink": "Coffiee"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "John",
    "drink": "Latte"
}]
```

Comment: Why are there different url's? When you post data you are posting to `/api/orders` does this url exist or it is a typo?

Comment: what error are u getting in ur console

Comment: I am getting "Error Adding Orders"

Comment: @PeterDarmis I have edited my URL but it is still not working.

Comment: @RahulKashyap How are you handling the POST request in orders.json? Your ajax request works but the response that you're getting is 500 since you might not have handled it properly in orders.json.

Comment: @BharatGeleda How am I supposed to handle JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Client side scripting languages are used to send and retrieve data which resides on server side. We can't use them to write/edit data on server side**.

For doing so, we have to use server side scripting languages like **PHP** or **ASP** or any other which you prefer.

The video you referred was an API written in Core PHP used for retrieving / writing data from / to a json file which resides on server.

In my below code i have used PHP to write submitted data to a json file via jQuery/AJAX.

Check this out..

> **api/process.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['params'])) {
  $params = $_POST['params'];

  $oldData = file_get_contents('orders.json');
  $tmp = json_decode($oldData);
  array_push($tmp, $params);
  $newData = json_encode($tmp);

  if (is_writable('orders.json')) {
    file_put_contents('orders.json', $newData);
    echo $newData;
  } else {
    echo "file is not writable, check permissions";
  }
}
```

> **index.html**

```
<h1>Jquery  Ajax Tutorial</h1>

<h3>Coffie Orders</h3>

<ul id="orders"></ul>

<h4>Add a Coffie Order</h4>
<p>  Name: <input type="text" id="name"> </p>
<p>  Drink: &nbsp;<input type="text" id="drink"> </p>
<button id="add-order">Add!</button>
<script src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/main.js'></script>
```

> **js/main.js**

```
let $orders = $('#orders');
let $name = $('#name');
let $drink = $('#drink');

function addOrder(order) {
  $orders.append('<li>Name: '+ order.name +', Drink: '+ order.drink +'</li>');
}

$('#add-order').click(function(){
  let order = {
    name: $name.val(),
    drink: $drink.val()
  };

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/process.php',
    data: { params: order },
    success: function(resp) {
      addOrder(resp);
    },
    error: function(){
      alert('Error Adding Orders');
    }
  });
});

$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/api/orders.json',
  success: function (orders) {
    $.each(orders, function(i, orders) {
      addOrder(orders);
    });
  },
  error: function(){
    alert('Error Loading Page');
  }
});
```

> **api/orders.json**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "James",
    "drink": "Coffiee"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "John",
    "drink": "Latte"
  }
]
```

**Note:** Here, i am not writing `id` to json file for new orders.

Hope, this piece of code works fine for you. :) :)

Comment: @ChiatanyaGhule he is not using PHP in video which I am referring.

Comment: My question is that when his code is working why mine is not working.He has done this without using PHP.

Comment: in, my post i have written it in bold letters about client-side scripting lang. you can clarify your doubt click here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875435/how-to-send-data-to-json-file-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: Okay I get it but how his code is working. I can't see that he is using any php file.

Comment: I am also not sure about the URL order in the video so that is he using json file or he is using order file which has no extension. All I know is that he has used json.

Comment: ya i have went thru his video he has designed his own API for doing that it it can only be done with help of server side scripting languages. as u can see his url in ajax request has path 'api/orders' that means he is using .htaccess file to map the request uri to actual location by writing rules for uri mapping..

Comment: you can do the same but my research says that using jQuery/AJAX we can only retrieve and send data, still now i have never seen client side tech. used to store data in db or write data to json files on residing on server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152898/discussion-between-rahul-kashyap-and-chaitanya-ghule).